# Why doesn't Text::Balanced::extract_bracketed extract the text inside a LaTeX tag?

Tags: perl, parsing, latex

I am trying to parse balanced text (actually, text written in LaTeX) using [`extract_bracketed`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Balanced#extract_bracketed) from Text::Balanced. However, I did not get a correct match with the following code:

```
use Text::Balanced qw(extract_bracketed);

my $data = 'xxx \footnote{...} yyy';
(my $ext, my $rem, my $pre) = extract_bracketed($data, '{}', '\footnote');
print "\$ext = $ext\n";
print "\$rem = $rem\n";
print "\$pre = $pre\n";
```

This prints:

```
$ext =                                                                                                                  
$rem = xxx \footnote{...} yyy                                                                                           
$pre =
```

According to the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Balanced#extract_bracketed), this output means that a failure occurred, but I do not understand why.

What I actually want to extract is `...`, i.e. the contents of the `\footnote` command.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Text::Balanced sets `$@` on failure so you can get [details about the cause](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Balanced#DIAGNOSTICS):

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use 5.010;

use Text::Balanced qw(extract_bracketed);

my $text = 'xxx \footnote{...} yyy';
my ($substring, $remainder, $prefix) = extract_bracketed($text, '{}', '\footnote');

warn $@ if $@;
```

Output:

```
Did not find prefix: /\footnote/, detected at offset 0 at balanced line 12.
```

The prefix didn't match because:

- it has to match from the beginning of the string all the way to the first occurrence of the delimiter
- `\f` matches a form feed, not a literal backslash followed by the letter f

The following prefix matches everything up to the first curly brace:

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use 5.010;

use Text::Balanced qw(extract_bracketed);

my $text = 'xxx \footnote{...} yyy';

my ($substring, $remainder, $prefix) = extract_bracketed($text, '{}', '[^{}]*');
say "<$_>" for $prefix, $substring, $remainder;
```

Output:

```
<xxx \footnote>
<{...}>
< yyy>
```

To actually *remove* a nested footnote tag from the text, leaving its contents, you need to use `extract_tagged`:

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use 5.010;

use Text::Balanced qw(extract_tagged);

my $text = '\footnote{abc \footnote{...} def \emph{!!!} ghi}';

my @pieces = extract_tagged(
    $text, 
    '\\\footnote{', 
    '}', 
    '(?s).*\\\footnote{.*(?=\\\footnote{)'
);

my ($remainder, $prefix, $contents) = @pieces[1, 2, 4];

say $prefix . $contents . $remainder;
```

Output:

```
\footnote{abc ... def \emph{!!!} ghi}
```

---

Note that this approach works for the simple input you gave, but won't work as a general-purpose LaTeX parser. There are a couple of LaTeX parsers on CPAN, but [LaTeX::TOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/LaTeX::TOM) looks fairly limited and [LaTeX::Parser](https://metacpan.org/pod/LaTeX::Parser) hasn't been updated since 2000.

If you need to do more complex parsing, you may need to write your own parser.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I misunderstood the meaning of "prefix", obviously. The piece of code you provided works for all LaTeX commands, not only \footnote. But what I am interested in is extracting footnotes only... more precisely, what I ultimately want to do is remove any \footnote nested in a \footnote (please do not ask why I am facing such nesting, it is no worth explaining !). Any ideas ?

Comment: @YvesdeSaint-Pern If you change the pattern to `'.*\\\footnote'` you can extract the contents of the most nested footnote, including the curly braces. Is that what you want?

Comment: I want to convert
`\footnote{abc \footnote{...} def \emph{!!!} ghi}`

into:
`\footnote{abc ... def \emph{!!!} ghi}`

Comment: Very interesting but unfortunately the content of the footnote (... in my example above) is removed with your suggestion. I would like to keep it (as plain text, not as a nested footnote).

Comment: I further note that your suggestion does not handle correctly the following string `my $text = '\footnote{abc {...} def \emph{!!!} ghi}';` sinces it matches its unique footnote although it is not a nested one...

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what you wanted, see update. Let me reiterate that Text::Balanced works for the limited input you've given, but won't work as a general LaTeX parser; don't expect it to work for all inputs. You need a real parser for that.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help !